# How to set page title in single page site

Tags: php

Hi I have a single page ajax website the single page is basically loading all the pages I would like to set the page title depending on the current view.

I have tried using this

```
<title><!--TITLE--></title>
    <?
$pageContents = ob_get_contents (); // Get all the page's HTML into a string
ob_end_clean (); // Wipe the buffer

// Replace <!--TITLE--> with $pageTitle variable contents, and print the HTML
echo str_replace ('<!--TITLE-->', $pageTitle, $pageContents);
?>
```

I have then added the titles to the page links like this

```
  <li class="menu-link">
        <a href="index.php?page=home"><img src="images/menu/home.png" width="72" height="72" alt="Home" />Home</a>
        <?php $pageTitle = 'Saunders-Solutions Freelance Design and Development'; ?>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-link">
        <a href="index.php?page=about"><img src="images/menu/about.png" width="72" height="72" alt="About" />About</a>
        <?php $pageTitle = 'About Saunders-Solutions Freelance Design and Development';  ?>
    </li>
```

however it always shows the same title for all pages any help appreciated

Comment: did you called `ob_start();`?

Comment: try moving ur <?php $pageTitle= .. above ur <a> tag..

Answer (score 0):

in javascript:

```
document.title = "New Title";
```

Answer (score 0):

variable $pageTitle  seems to be defined after the replacement with str_replace take place. 
Maybe you could post more code to see what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Can You Just Print The HTML?
Works Fine For Me.

```
print "<TITLE>".$pageTitle."</TITLE>";
```

Then Just Remove Any Other Code That Sets The Title:

Eg:

```
<title><!--TITLE--></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$TITLE[home]="Saunders-Solutions Freelance Design and Development";
$TITLE[about]="About Saunders-Solutions Freelance Design and Development";
?>

<title><?=$TITLE[$_GET[page]]?></title>

<li class="menu-link">
        <a href="index.php?page=home"><img src="images/menu/home.png" width="72" height="72" alt="Home" />Home</a>            
    </li>
    <li class="menu-link">
        <a href="index.php?page=about"><img src="images/menu/about.png" width="72" height="72" alt="About" />About</a>

    </li>
```